# Python Sphinx Substitutions not throwing errors or warnings like ref's

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution

In an effort to make the .rst files more readable I started using substitutions instead of refs everywhere for common objects.  For example :ref:`user-story` is now |user story|.  The output is fine, but when a user mistypes a substitution we do not see any errors when we execute make livehtml like we do when we use :refs:.  Is there a way to see undefined references like we do with ref's.

I've tried, with no success.
make livehtml -W
make livehtml -Wv

I do see errors like duplicate substitutions, but not unresolved substitutions.

Sphinx 1.4.6

Windows 10

Python 2.7.11

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. A reference to an undefined substitution makes Sphinx emit 'ERROR: Undefined substitution referenced: "TEST"'.

Comment: Sorry to bump, in favor of tidiness you should accept the solution if it solved the problem. Otherwise the question shows as unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error using -n for nit-picky mode displayed undefined substitution errors when building.

```
make livehtml -n
```